# How do I tell if a value exists anywhere in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am loading datasets via Spark and need to ensure that the imported data doesn't contain certain values anywhere in the dataframe (for now, Null, NaN, and empty string, but there might be others later). All I need is to know "Does there exist at least one value x, y, or z anywhere in the dataframe?". What is the computationally best approach to getting this boolean response?

I'd prefer something like below and something that succeeds quickly (returns True upon finding the first instance; only reads the entire dataframe in the case that it returns False).

```py
bad_value: bool = df.exists([None, float("NaN"), "", "foo"])
```

Here is a naïve approach, however, this performs an expensive count operation and uses a loop:

```py
from typing import Any

from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan


def val_in_df(df: DataFrame, val: Any) -> bool:
  for c in df.columns:
    count = df.filter((df[c] == val)).count()
    if count > 0:
      return True

  return False


df = spark.read.csv("untrusted/data/file.csv", header=True)

if val_in_df(df, None):
  print("There is a null in the df")

if val_in_df(df, float("NaN")):
  print("There is a NaN in the df")

if val_in_df(df, "")):
  print("There is an empty string in the df")

if val_in_df(df, "foo"):
  print("The string 'foo' is a value somewhere in the df")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.reduce` to chain the filter conditions. Here's an example for nulls check over all the columns :

```
import functools
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

null_cols = [col(c).isNull() for c in df.columns]

filter_null_condition = functools.reduce(
    lambda acc, x: acc | x, null_cols[1:], null_cols[0]
)

nulls_count = df.filter(filter_null_condition).count()

if nulls_count:
    print("There is a null in the df")
```